# Android Tablayout: 3 Tabs, let center tab take 70% of available width

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm currently using a [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) in my application.

I set `GRAVITY_FILL` and `MODE_FIXED` but that does not accomplish what I want.
I have **3 tabs** all the time. The left and the right tab header only show a small Icon while the middle tab has a long text.

This is what I want:

**[________TOTAL WIDTH__________]**

**[Icon][A very long tab header][Icon2]**

This is how it looks like:

**[__________________________TOTAL WIDTH__________________________]**

**[_________Icon________][A very long tab header][_________Icon2________]**

So as you can hopefully see from my poor illustration I want to have the middle tab take about 70% of the space and give the rest to the 2 tabs with the icons.

Now I have already done some research and people suggest that I extend some of the layout classes but I could not get it to work.

Can someone please be so kind to let me know if this is possible and how I would achieve it.

Comment: may be this will help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: How would that work with a TabLayout? I dont't see a way to change the layout manager?

Comment: i haven't use TabLayout i sent you for clue that may be percentLayout can use in it

Comment: It is impossible to use percents with `TabLayout`. Tabs are laid out in a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the only solution of your problem

```
    int padding_in_dp = 2;  // 6 dps
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int padding_in_px = (int) (padding_in_dp * scale + 0.5f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.newTab();
        mTabLayout.addTab(tab);
        LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(i));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layout.setPadding(padding_in_px, 0, padding_in_px, 0);
        tab.setText(array[i]);
    }
```

It will surely help you

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this as soon as I can!

Comment: Thank you so much again for reading my question and providing the perfect answer!